# It is possible to generate sequence diagram from python code?

Tags: python, sequence-diagram

I have about 700 lines of code. I have to write a little doc about this code. In this doc, I plan to have a sequence diagram to explain a bit more. something like this: [image] Since Iam a bit lazy, I would like to know if there is a tool to generate this diagram from code. I don't want to lose my entire weekend doing this.

Do some have an idea that could help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly offtopic for SO, but checkout networkx https://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html or if you want. Also workflow managers like ruffus http://ruffus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ or snakemake http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 3):

I was searching for this topic too and found the following usefull:
https://github.com/bereal/pyspy

It patches the bytecode using [byteplay](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ByteplayDoc) and you can add your own callback-functions to do something before each call and after each. Similar to writting a profiler using `sys.settrace` but easier.

Well, I added some fixes as issue-comments because I was not able to use git properly from here. Your functions may write DLS as text, like is needed by [PlantUML](http://plantuml.com/) or [ZenUML](https://app.zenuml.com)... and use it to generate your diagram.

Comment: This question is OT here ("Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam") and should have been closed as such.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: yes, I know, but I must admid, that I search for recommendation in SO too and I'm happy when I found an answer... :-)

Answer (score 3):

The Plantuml in python could be helpful. For how to install use link
[PlantUML with python](https://blog.toast38coza.me/easy-plantuml-with-python/)

Text file should be like so:

```
Python -> HL : create
activate HL
HL -> LL : run
activate LL
LL -> SLI : exec
activate SLI
SLI --> LL
deactivate SLI
LL --> HL
deactivate LL
HL -> LL : push
activate LL
LL -> SLI : push
activate SLI
SLI --> LL
deactivate SLI
LL --> HL
deactivate LL
HL -> LL : run
activate LL
LL -> SLI : exec
activate SLI
SLI --> LL
deactivate SLI
LL --> HL
deactivate LL
HL -> LL : pop
activate LL
LL -> SLI : pop
activate SLI
SLI --> LL
deactivate SLI
LL --> HL
deactivate LL
HL --> Python
deactivate HL
```

[image]

It is possible to generate the text by python for this purpose, for example, you can add after the method declaration.

```
print>>sd.txt, "->"+str(self.name)+":className"
```

This will append to sd.txt and finally create png file in the project directory by running:

```
python -m plantuml sd.txt
```

[python-UML-sequence-diagram](https://github.com/backman-git/python-UML-sequence-diagram)

Comment: Something to keep in mind is that it will send your data to an external server. I tested it locally with test data and it works, I just wouldn't use this specific one for company "secret stuff".

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple tracing class and an example of what can be done with it.
instantiate the class at the beginning of each function you want to trace.
A decorator could also be done on the same principle but you would have to adapt the python frame parsing accordingly

```
class SequenceOn:
   autonumber = True
   init_done = False

def __init__(self,participant=""):

    if not SequenceOn.init_done :
        #activate if requested only once
        if SequenceOn.autonumber: 
            print ("autonumber")

        SequenceOn.init_done = True

    #retrieve callee frame
    callee_frame = sys._getframe(1)

    #method/function name
    self.__funcName = callee_frame.f_code.co_name

    # look for a class name
    if 'self' in callee_frame.f_locals:
        self.__className = callee_frame.f_locals['self'].__class__.__name__
    else:
        self.__className = participant

    #retrieve the caller frame and class name of the caller
    caller_frame = sys._getframe(2)

    if 'self' in caller_frame.f_locals:
        self.__caller = caller_frame.f_locals['self'].__class__.__name__
    else:
        self.__caller = ""

    #print the plantuml message
    activate = "++" if self.__caller != self.__className else ""
    print (f'{self.__caller} -> {self.__className} {activate} :{self.__funcName}')


def __del__(self):
    ''' print the return message upon destruction '''
    if self.__caller != self.__className:
        print (f'{self.__caller} <-- {self.__className} -- ')

def note(self,msg):
    print (f'note over {self.__className}:{msg}')

class SequenceOff:
    ''' empty class allowing to disable the trace by eg doing in the begining of a file:

    Seq = SequenceOn # enable sequence generation
    Seq = SequenceOff # disable sequence generation

    and using seq for tracing instead of SequenceOn
    '''
    def __init__(self,participant=""):
        pass
    def __call__(self,msg):
        pass
    def note(self,msg):
        pass
```

On the below sample code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def funcB1(self):
        s = SequenceOn()

    def funcB2(self):
        s = SequenceOn()
        s.note("calling private method")
        self.__funcB22()

    def __funcB22(self):
        s = SequenceOn()

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def funcA(self):

        s = SequenceOn()
        b = B()
        b.funcB1()
        b.funcB2()

# simple sequence
a = A()
a.funcA()
```

You get:

```
autonumber
 -> A ++ :funcA
A -> B ++ :funcB1
A <-- B --
A -> B ++ :funcB2
note over B:calling private method
B -> B  :__funcB22
A <-- B --
 <-- A --
```

Which generates:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But may I know if there is a way to generate sequence diagrams from static python source code without altering it?